# Find the region of the plane given by the equation $z^2 = i|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In order to find the region described by

$$z^2 = i|z|^2$$

I did:

$$z = a+bi \rightarrow |z|^2 = a^2+b^2 \rightarrow i|z|^2 = a^2i+b^2i$$

$$z = a+bi \rightarrow z^2 = a^2 + 2ab -b^2$$

$$z^2 = i|z|^2 \rightarrow a^2 + 2ab -b^2 =  a^2i+b^2i \rightarrow (a^2+2ab-b^2)-(a^2+b^2)i = 0 \rightarrow $$

$$a^2+2ab-b^2 = 0$$

which gave me a pair of intersecting lines. Am I right? It's kinda strange that a complex equation gives me a [pair of lines](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2B2xy%20-y%5E2%20%3D%200)

Comment: Wait, $z^2$ is NOT equal to $a^2+2ab-b^2$, the middle term should be $2abi$

Comment: You have $2ab$ where you need $2abi$. $\qquad$

Comment: There is an easier way to do this.. $|z|^2$ is always real and positive so $i|z|^2$ is always on the nonnegative $y$-axis. For which $z$ does this happen?

Comment: There is another easier way to do this...: Remember that $|z|^2 = z\bar z$, so, one $z$ will cancel out.

Comment: @Physicist137 Good one!

Comment: @imranfat When you cancel out, you are assuming $z\neq 0$. So, you need to consider the $z=0$ case separately. And $z=0$ is trivially a solution. =).

Comment: @Physicist137. yes, makes sense, and it is only y=x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the absolute values of $z^2$ and $i|z^2|$ are the same no matter which complex number $z$ is, since $|i|=1$.  And you know $i|z|^2$ is a pure imaginary.  So $z^2$ must also be a pure imaginary. If $z= r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ then $z^2= r^2(\cos(2\theta) + i\sin(2\theta))$.  So you need $\cos(2\theta)=0$.  That's two straight lines through the origin.

Per Rahul's comment, this is not done yet.  The relation $\cos(2\theta)=0$ is also satisfied by some values of $z$ for which $z^2=-i|z^2|$.  You have to figure out which parts of those two lines that corresponds to.

Comment: This is incorrect. $z=1-i$ satisfies $\cos(2\arg z)=0$ but not $z^2=i|z|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $z=0$ is in the region. If $z\neq 0$ write $z=re^{it}$ with $r>0$ and $t \in [0,2\pi).$ The condition can be written $$r^2e^{2it}=ir^2,$$ which means $$e^{2it} =i.$$ But $2t \in [0,4\pi).$ So the only possibilities are $2t = \pi/2$ and $2t = 5\pi/2$. Hence $t = \pi/4$ or $t=5\pi/4$. Can you now draw the region ?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. let me transform my comment into an answer.

$z=0$ evidently satisfies. If $z\neq 0$, then:
$$
z^2 = i|z|^2 = iz\bar z \\
z = i\bar z \\
Re\{z\} = Im\{z\}
$$

All these steps are equivalent. And thus: $z = a + ai$,  $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ is the solution.